# Is gRPC Async server multi-threaded?

Tags: grpc

We have written a gRPC Async server/client to parallelize certain processing. I have a fundamental question on how the Async server works.

For example, say, we make two same Async calls from the client on a method but giving different inputs (half the amount of the original data) to each call so that we can parallelize this operation. What goes on, on the server side when we do this?

My assumption was that the server would queue up these two calls and then handle them simultaneously in two separate threads. But, this does not appear to be so.

The time taken to process one single call with all the original data turns out to be less than the combined time taken by the two Async calls of the same method with half the original data for each. Why is this so?

Thanks!

Comment: It's hard to answer this question since "async" is more of a concept and not a concrete system facility. For example, asynchronicity can be achieved via threads (as you say) or non-blocking system calls, or batched calls such as `select` or `epoll` or `kqueue` depending on the system/version/codebase age. You would have to consult the server's code in question to know for sure. As for asynchrous programming, it's best to assume nothing about the order or timeliness of execution. As for speedup, remember that oftentimes servers optimize for scaled usage, not individuals requests, too.

Comment: Hi there! Thanks for the response. My question was in the context of gRPC and my understanding of it. It is not clear from the gRPC Async examples as to what exactly goes on when we make Async calls from the client to the server. I appreciate any answer to this specific context.

Answer (score 0):

This almost isn't about gRPC but about machines distributed across networks and how a single machine (appears to) process multiple tasks (concurrently).

Perhaps a thought experiment (see below) will help explain some of the differences. In neither your question nor the thought experiment do we consider (the realistic scenario) that there is network latency, connection management time, and other processes underway.

With a single message, once the server has received it (and assuming it has negligible other demands on its time), it can process the data and return the result (ignoring that gRPC messages must be unmarshaled from the wire into protos and possible into different types for processing and then back again for transmission etc.).

With multiple messages, receipt of each interrupts the server, must be unmarshaled etc, processed, marshaled, transmitted etc.

If there were no other processes underway, no network latency, no connection setup|teardown etc., no (un)marshaling time, no processing overheads (e.g. getting a database connection for each message), no concurrent processing (messages arrive perfectly such that as one is completed, the next arrives), even then (!!) there are non-negligible processing overheads.

##### Single call

1. Your colleague (the `client`) emails you (the `server`) the data.
2. Upon receipt of the data, you process it and email back the results.

##### Multiple calls

1. You colleague splits the data into multiple emails to you.
2. Upon receipt of each email (!), you begin processing the data.
3. If another email arrives before you're done, you begin processing it too.
4. Give yourself a couple of seconds on each document but switch between them.
5. When you're done with each, email back the result to your colleague.

Additionally:

- before sending you the email, your colleague goes to lunch
- while processing at least one job, your dog needs to be taken for a walk.

Comment: Hi there! Thanks for the detailed explanation. But I am looking for an answer specifically with respect to gRPC ASync implementation. May be my wordings were wrong. I know the difference between sync and ASync distributed architectures. I think I have fairly clearly mentioned that the problem I am facing with gRPC ASync  usage of mine is that when I make two Async calls from the Async client to a gRPC ASync service, the tasks appear to be serialized rather than being executed in Parallel, which was my expectation. I expect any answers specifically in this context.

Comment: It's highly unlikely that any server would serialize requests. The only time gRPC servers serialize processing is when a client streams messages in serial. You may want to add the server language to your question. I'm unaware of any single-threaded gRPC servers beyond Python but even then, the host runtime will process requests concurrently.